# Looking to restrict window edges to grid

Tags: window-manager, tiling

I happen to be fortunate enough to use a very large monitor and would like to place my 4-8 windows on my display in such a way that they are aligned with each other. I am aware of tiling window managers but have found the learning curve too steep for the limited benefit they provide.

I was wondering if a tool existed that merely restricted resizing and movement of windows to a grid of configurable granularity, or if such a tool does not exist, what direction I might want to move in to hack one together for myself.